Writing a query to return records from one table using records selected from two other tables by their association to a fourth table
I have four tables that are immediately relevant to the question, though there are two others peripherally involved, which I’ll describe for completeness, marked *
Data:



ID
Name
Description
tag
catid
gid




num
text
text
text
num
num



Categories*:



catid
catname




num
text



Groups*:



gid
gname




num
text



Searches:



sid
term
mode




num
text
num



SearchCategories:



sid
catid




num
num



SearchGroups:



sid
gid




num
num



What i want is a query that, given a single sid returns records from Data where:

some (which and how many depend on mode value) of the text fields contain a partial match to the Search.term field
the catid value matches a record from SearchCategories that has the given sid
the gid value matches a record from SearchGroups that has the given sid

I am working in MS Access for now, and cannot switch to a different setup at this time
My apologies if this is basically a question that has been asked in a different form before, i have searched, but i might have used wrong search terms.
